# Replacing a sub-string in JavaScript innerHTML

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an HTML page which contains table rows like

```
    <tr id="tp1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tc_">
     </tr> 
    <tr id="tp2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tc_">
    </tr>
```

The page contains input elements other than checkboxes as well
I have to change the values of all checkbox's id from tc_ to tc_1 ,tc_2 and so on.
I have thought of doing it as below

```
function startup(){
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        var elem=document.getElementById("tp"+i);
        var str=elem.innerHTML;
        str.replace(/tc_,'tc_'+i);  // how do I correctly use the arguments here?
        elem.innerHTML=str;
        //alert (""+str);
     }
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: It isn't valid to have non-unique IDs in the first place. Any chance you can fix how the checkboxes are rendered so you don't have to do this?

Comment: HTML will render perfectly well here on Stack Overflow (enter the HTML, select that HTML and then hit the `{}` button (or 'ctrl + K')), in precisely the same way as the JavaScript you posted. See the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) for more guidance.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a pure javascript way to do this?  I would drop all the id values and then subsequently use jquery here as its going to be the easiest way.

Comment: I know this is not an ideal solution,the problem with id values is due to Sphinx and I don't know much about it and didn't have any answer for my earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278105/replacing-id-attributes-of-checkboxes-in-html-using-innerhtml so just looking for a workaround though it's a poor way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't valid to have non-unique IDs in the first place. Any chance you can fix how the checkboxes are rendered so you don't have to do this?

That being said, I wouldn't do this by manipulating the HTML attributes. I would instead do this by manipulating the DOM properties of those input checkboxes:

```
// keep track of the current "new" checkbox ID suffix
var checkBoxIndex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // find the table row
    var elem = document.getElementById("tp" + i);
    // get the input elements within that row
    var inputs = elem.getElementsByTagName("input");
    // for each of the input elements...
    for (var j = 0, k = inputs.length; j < k; j++) {
        // if it's not a checkbox, skip it
        if (inputs[j].type.toLowerCase() !== 'checkbox') {
            continue;
        }
        // Alas, give the checkbox a new, unique ID
        inputs[j].id = "tc_" + (checkBoxIndex++);
    }
}
```

Also, hopefully you get an answer for your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278105/replacing-id-attributes-of-checkboxes-in-html-using-innerhtml). This is a terrible workaround and  I would hate to see it in production code.

Comment: I am sorry i didn't make it clear the markup is just a sample,the page contains other input tags as well and not just checkboxes

Comment: You may be able to put a check for that on the inside of the second for-loop. Something like: if (checkboxes[j].type === 'checkbox') ...

Comment: @user2863649: See my edits; I added a check for the type as Katana suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to select all the input elements of your rows using the appropriate CSS selector, then modify their ids:

```
function startup() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3;i++) {
     var elem = document.getElementById("tp" + i);

     var l = elem.querySelectorAll('td > input'); // Select "input"s in "td"s
     Array.prototype.forEach.call(l, function (e, j) { // Apply to each element obtained
       e.id = 'tc_' + j; // Modify the id
     });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several good answers above but if you still want to change the id from tc_ to tc_ + i then you can do it like this.

```
<body>
<button id="tc_">1</button>
<button id="tc_">2</button>
<button id="tc_">3</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
document.getElementById("tc_").id="tc_"+i;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Honestly though you shouldn't be doing it like this despite the fact this code works as other users have said it isn't  valid to have non-unique id's.